# How do positive ions help in conducting electricity?

Tags: electrochemistry

I understand that positive ions usually move towards the negative electrode and gain back their electron(s). But how is this considered as the positive ions helping to conduct electricity?

Comment: Same as negative ions do.

Comment: Two things that may help you: (1) the 'electricity' you mention is exactly the motion of the ions across the electrolytic solution, they are the same thing, (2) what 'helps/not helps' conducting the electricity is the potential differences established across the interfaces in an electrochemical cell; no potential differences and we get no movement of ions, huge potential differences and we get huge density currents. You may get some ohmic loss in the bulk of the electrolytic solution, that will affect the movement too.

Comment: You might look at: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/144010/do-ions-still-conduct-electricity-if-a-physical-connection-made-by-aqueous-ele?rq=1

Comment: As an external macroscopic observer, how to you distinguish a positive charge moving to the right from a negative charge moving to the left? They both yield the same net charge flow (i.e. current).

Answer (score 1):

A definition of conduction is "moving charges from one place to another." Positive ions are charged particles. They move. That is conduction.

As an aside, in metals, conduction is like the action in [Newton's cradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cradle). Electrons bump other electrons, rather than each migrating the whole distance; the [drift velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity) is **far** slower than the speed of signal propagation. The same can be true of ions in liquids, but ions in a *rarefied* gas may travel the whole distance.